# Is it possible to athenticate using Kerberos against a Kerberos enabled domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos, siebel

We are configuring a Siebel to authenticate against a Microsoft Active Directory with Kerberos enabled.

Kerberos authentication is not enabled in Siebel under Unix so we're planning to use simple authentication.

It is possible to authenticate to a Microsoft Active Directory without Kerberos when Kerberos is enabled in the domain controller?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can authenticate to a Microsoft Active Directory without Kerberos, using either NTLM or LDAP.  NTLM though, is disabled by default in AD 2008 and above.  LDAP authentication through bind calls can be used as well by application servers who can't do ether NTLM or Kerberos.  Classically, LDAP is meant as a directory lookup protocol and not really meant as an authentication protocol.  Typically, these scenarios involve application servers running on non-Microsoft platforms.  Be advised that Kerberos is the most secure protocol of the three and is the industry standard for authentication.